# Enabling post thumbnails for custom post type

Tags: posts, functions

I'm writing a custom post type as a plugin and trying to figure out how I can enable post thumbnails within plugin documentation/template instead of enabling it in the functions.php. I tried adding the code below inside custom-post-plugin.php and it doesn't seem to work. I still have to write the code within the functions.php to enable post thumbnails for my custom post

```
/ * ADD THUMBNAIL FOR POST
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post', 'custom-post' ) );
```

Sample code below

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Example Custom Post Plugin
Description: Example post plugin for News and Press custom post
*/
?>

<?php
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ *
 * EXAMPLE CUSTOM POST
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

function example () {

// Set UI labels for Custom Post Type
    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'Example', 'Post Type General Name', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'Example', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Example', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Example', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All Post', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'View Post', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Post', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'Add Post', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Post', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update Post', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search Post', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'Not Found', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'twentythirteen' ),
    );

// Set other options for Custom Post Type

    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'Example', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'description'         => __( 'Example', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        // Features this CPT supports in Post Editor
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', ),
        // You can associate this CPT with a taxonomy or custom taxonomy.
        'taxonomies'          => array('category', 'post_tag'),
        /* A hierarchical CPT is like Pages and can have
        * Parent and child items. A non-hierarchical CPT
        * is like Posts.
        */
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 4,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'page',
    );

    // Registering your Custom Post Type
    register_post_type( 'example', $args );
}

/* Hook into the 'init' action so that the function
* Containing our post type registration is not
* unnecessarily executed.
*/

add_action( 'init', 'example', 'example', 1 );

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'example_featured_image');
function example_featured_image() {
        add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post', 'page', 'production_firm', 'example' ) );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are most probably using [`add_theme_support()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support#Post_Thumbnails) in the wrong context (*hook*).

Because you are [registering the post type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) yourself, all you need to do is to add support for thumbnails in the `supports` array when you pass your your arguments to `register_post_type()`

> ***`supports`***
>
> (array/boolean) (optional) An alias for calling `add_post_type_support()` directly. As of 3.5, boolean false can be passed as value instead of an array to prevent default (title and editor) behavior.
>
> Default: title and editor

All you need to do is to pass `thumbnail` to the array

```
'supports' => ['title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'], // Add additional values as needed
```

You would also need to [check if support for thumbnails is enabled](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_theme_supports) by the theme, and if not, add post thumbnail support in your plugin.

Comment: I just checked my code and "thumbnail' is already added in the array. Here is my code if you want to check on it

http://pastie.org/10764783

Not sure what I'm doing wrong,

Comment: Here is my updated code http://pastie.org/10764842 and it's still not working. I checked the "screen options" and featured image is not showing

Comment: Please post your code as an edit to your question. Sorry, your theme support should be hooked to `after_setup_theme`, not `init`. For somne silly reason I typed `init`. Your code should work. Have you flushed your permalinks?. If the thumbnail metabox still don't show, disable all plugins and test your plugin on a bundled theme

Comment: Thank you sir, managed to make it work with your help :)

Comment: My pleasure, glad it worked. Enjoy and good luck with your project ;-)